# Consumir WCF em localhost no VS2008 (Windows CE)

Tags: visual-studio, wcf

Estou tentando consumir um WCF (localhost) em uma aplicação Windows CE no VS2008. Se eu tento fazer a mesma coisa no VS2010, tudo funciona já que ele cria automaticamente o proxy (app.config).

Quando executo a linha de teste:

```
 var t = WebServiceConnection.webservice.Teste("v1.0.0.1");
```

Recebo a seguinte exceção:

```
{System.Net.WebException: WebException
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.doInvoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters, WebClientAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at GPAColetor.ServicePicking.ColetaService.Teste(String parametro)
   at GPAColetor.VIEW.FrmLogin..ctor()
   at GPAColetor.Program.Main()
}
```

Alguma dica de como resolver isso?

Comment: Veja se lhe ajuda:      http://www.techbubbles.com/net-framework/wcf-sample-in-visual-studio-2008/

Comment: Obrigado meu caro Paulo, mas o exemplo mostra a criação de um wcf. Meu WCF é estável, o problema ta na hora de consumir mesmo. Quando eu consumo ele no vs2010, seja hospedado no IIS da maquina ou no IIS Express do VS2010, funciona bem, consigo até debugar. Quando chega no VS2008 é que começa o suplicio.